# passing value from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need your help in this particular issue
I want to pass the value of a hidden input type in a .jsp program to a servlet program

what I am doing is basically this

```
<input type="hidden" name="articleId" id="articleId" value=" <%request.getParameter("articleId");%>"/>
```

and from the servlet I am getting the value

```
String articleId = request.getParameter("message");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(articleId);
```

It doesn't print any think . the jsp form method is post and the servlet method is doPost

any Ideas why it doesn't pass the parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used wrong parameter, should do as following:

```
String articleId = request.getParameter("articleId");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(articleId);
```

Comment: yea I did change that but still cannot see the passed value, I tried to get value from some other jsp form component it does work if I don't specify the value in the code. but what I want to see is the value of the hidden component from the servlet.

Comment: @user1210237 make sure your hidden input is in `form` tag as well.

Answer (score 3):

1: change your input value(you forget <%**=**):

```
<input type="hidden" name="articleId" id="articleId" value="<%=request.getParameter("articleId");%>" />
```

2: change your argument in getParamater:

```
String articleId = request.getParameter("articleId");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(articleId);
```