# JSP pass hidden input value to servlet when the page load

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I should be using getRemoteUser functionality to get the logged in user. Until the authentication part get created I am trying to hard code the user in the jsp page and pass that in the my servlet. But when I try to print out the value its null:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value="123456789" />
```

Here is how I tried to get the user:

```
    String fakeUser = request.getParameter("userId");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(fakeUser);
    System.out.println(fakeUser)
```

I also tried the solution mentioned following Stackoverflow post but that didn't work either. 
[passing value from jsp to servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268415/passing-value-from-jsp-to-servlet)

Comment: The input must be in a form that is submitted (by button or JavaScript).

Comment: @JoopEggen Is there any other way to pass a variable in to servlet via JSP?

Comment: I don't understand, I ask legitimate question and its being down voted. Very hostile environment :)

Comment: (I did not downvote.) Downvoting also occurs when the question is not very interesting / useful for others. _Objectionable_ questions are treated with 'flag'. So you are in good company.

Comment: General one passes from a servlet forward to jsp using `request.setAttribute("msg", "Hello");` and then in the JSP uses `${msg}`. Also for lists etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to use `hidden-form field` I assume that you are trying to do some sort of `state management`.

try something like this

```
<form action="urlOfYourServlet" method="post">
    Enter your name : <input type ="text" name = "name"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="Welcome">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

In servlet

```
 String getHiddenValue=request.getParameter("hidden");
 String name=request.getParameter("name");
 System.out.println(name+" Hidden field Value is :"+getHiddenValue);
```

**Disadvantage :**

1. Only textual information can be persisted between request.
2. This method works only when the request is submitted through input form

Instead try `url-redirecting` or `HttpSession`